# ng-bootstrap Datepicker: Is there a way to select more than one date at once?

Tags: datepicker, ng-bootstrap

I'm in need of a calendar widget and, since I'm using Bootstrap 4 and ng-bootstrap in my current project, I'd like to know if the ng-boostrap widget support the multiselection of dates in some way.

I've already tried the wijmo Calendar for multiselection, but without success. Otherwise, can you recommend me a datepicker widget that has this capability?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, the [ng-bootstrap datepicker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples) supports range selection. You'll need to do manual conversion between the `NgbDateStruct` and a JavaScript `Date` object.

[image]

Comment: Great to know this, but is there a way to select separate dates or separate ranges without writing custom code? It would be great to know in advance. Thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. You want to select multiple dates, but not necessarily ranges? Like, July 1, July 12, and July 23? I don't think that's possible with ng-bootstrap.

Comment: did anyone find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

This can help

```
<p>This datepicker uses a custom template to display days.</p>

<ngb-datepicker
  [showWeekNumbers]="true"
  [dayTemplate]="customDay"
  (dateSelect)="selectOne($event)"
></ngb-datepicker>

<ng-template
  #customDay
  let-date
  let-currentMonth="currentMonth"
  let-selected="selected"
  let-disabled="disabled"
  let-focused="focused"
>
  <span
    class="custom-day"
    [class.focused]="focused"
    [class.bg-primary]="isSelected(date)"
    >{{ date.day }}</span
  >
</ng-template>
<div *ngIf="modelList.length>0">
  <h1>Selected dates:</h1>
  <pre>{{modelList| json}} </pre>
</div>
```

### TypeScript

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  NgbCalendar,
  NgbDate,
  NgbDateStruct,
} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-datepicker-customday',
  templateUrl: './datepicker-customday.html',
  styles: [
    `
    .custom-day {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 0.185rem 0.25rem;
      border-radius: 0.25rem;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 2rem;
    }
    .custom-day:hover, .custom-day.focused {
      background-color: #e6e6e6;
    }
    .bg-primary {
      border-radius: 1rem;
    }
  `,
  ],
})
export class NgbdDatepickerCustomday {
  model: NgbDateStruct;
  modelList: Array<NgbDateStruct> = [];

  constructor(private calendar: NgbCalendar) {}


  isSelected = (date: NgbDate) => {
    return this.modelList.indexOf(date) >= 0;
  };
  selectOne(date) {
    if (this.modelList.indexOf(date) >= 0) {
      this.modelList = this.modelList.filter(function (ele) {
        return ele != date;
      });
    } else {
      this.modelList.push(date);
    }
    console.log(this.modelList);
  }
}
```

[Demo stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zv7hdl?file=src/app/datepicker-customday.ts)